# Show that a function is not integrable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

show that $f(x,y) = \dfrac{2xy}{1+x^4+y^4}$ is not $\lambda_2$ integrable.

I am given the solution, and it states: $$\int f^+ \ d \lambda_2 \geq \int_{(0,\infty)^2} f^+  d \lambda_2 = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{2xy}{1+x^4+y^4} \ dy \ dx = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \dfrac{x}{1+x^4+y^2} \ dy dx$$ then they proceed to calculate the integral.

Also, they have $$\int f^- \ d \lambda_2 \geq \int _{(0,\infty) \times (-\infty,0)} f^- \ d \lambda_2 = \int f^+ \ d \lambda_2$$

I have some questions.

1) Where did the intequalities: $\int f^+ \ d \lambda_2 \geq \int_{(0,\infty)^2} f^+  d \lambda_2$ and $\int f^- \ d \lambda_2 \geq \int _{(0,\infty) \times (-\infty,0)} f^- \ d \lambda_2$ come from?

2) in the first set of inequalities, why did the "$2x$" change to $"x"$?

3) I am having troubles justifying why $\int _{(0,\infty) \times (-\infty,0)} f^- \ d \lambda_2 = \int f^+ \ d \lambda_2$ also

thank you

Comment: You are trying to show $\int_{\mathbb R^2} |f| d\lambda_2 = \infty,$ right?

Comment: yes I believe so

Answer (score 1):

1) $\int f^+ \ d \lambda_2 $ is the integral on the intervall $(-\infty,\infty)^2$ so since $f^+$ is positive, you have the inequality : $\int f^+ \ d \lambda_2 \geq \int_{(0,\infty)^2} f^+  d \lambda_2$. You have the other inequality with the same idea.

2) Actually it is not $x$ which changes, but $y$. If you make the substitution $u=y^2$, you have $du=2ydy$. And finally $\int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{2xy}{1+x^4+y^4} \ dy \ dx = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty \frac{x}{1+x^4+u^2} \ du dx$.

3) I have no idea at the moment...

Comment: I still don't really understand the inequalitie. I understand the first one, but with the second one - we have $f^-$ is positive aswell, so why did the interval change from $(-\infty,\infty)^2$ to $(-\infty,0)\times(0,\infty)$?

Comment: You just restric the intevall. When you integer a positive function on a smaller intervall, included in the original one, the integral is smaller, it is the property on positivity of the integral.

Comment: Ah OK, that makes sense thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach to this problem. Let $S$ be the infinite sector $\{re^{it}: 0 \le r <\infty, t \in [\pi/8,\pi/4]\}.$ Then

$$\int_{\mathbb R^2} f^+ \ge \int_{S} f.$$

Now let's start thinking in terms of polar coordinates. In $S,$

$$f(re^{it}) \ge \frac{2r^2\cos (\pi/4)\sin(\pi/8)}{1 + 2r^4} = C\frac{r^2}{1 + 2r^4}.$$

Integrating using polar coordinate gives

$$\int_{\pi/8}^{\pi/4} \int_0^\infty \frac{r^2}{1+2r^4}r\, dr\, dt=\infty.$$

The reason is that inner integral above diverges, because the integrand is on the order of $1/r$  for large $r.$ This shows $\int_{\mathbb R^2} f^+ = \infty.$ The argument for $\int_{\mathbb R^2} f^- = \infty$ is the same by symmetry.

Comment: How did you get the first inequality?

Comment: $f^+ = f$ on $S.$